# Inheritance in C++ multiple class issue

Tags: c++, inheritance

just a very simple question regarding inheritance in c++.

let's say I have a few classes.

Class A inherits from class B and from class C.

I want to make class D inherit from class A , but the functionality of class C is breaking my code.

Is it possible to somehow exclude class C when I inheriting from class A in class D?

edit:

@Quentin

I'm using SFML and class A inherits from the sf::NonCopyable class. Class A is the SceneNode class on which the hierarchy for all entities/objects in the game world is based. I was making a "TileEngine" class that produces instances of "TileLayer" objects and I wanted the TileLayers to inherit from SceneNode so that I can pass drawing calls onto them through the hierarchy but since they're non copyable I can't fit them into a container and iterate through them in the TileEngine class.

But I think you're right, it doesn't truly break the code. I think I'll just need to add a few variables and come up with a book keeping system to make it work.

I was just curious if what I asked was possible since it'd be an easy solution and I don't know all the ins and outs of using inheritance yet, so even though it seemed unlikely I decided to check. Thx for the replies I think I'll be able to adapt the code on my own.

Comment: Instead of describing your code with words, *show it!* Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: Sadly I don't think I can create an example using those guidlines. The classes are part of a framework I'm building for a 2D game. give me a sec and I'll at least post the constructors and the descriptions of their functionality

Comment: @fishyperil this is more about replacing the english description of `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` with a C++ snippet. I'm curious about how `C` "breaks" `D` though, so if you can reproduce that as well that'd be nice :)

Comment: "functionality of class C is breaking my code" this is a non-trivial statement, can you show what exactly happens?

Comment: @n.m. I explained in the edit. I'm sure there will be a workaround but I just wanted to check

Comment: @fishyperil: Even after the edit, I still don't see code. I know it takes some time to condense the problem to a minimal example, but please do so.

Answer (score 3):

Nope.

Your `A` *is* both a `B` and a `C`.
If `D` cannot be a `C`, then it cannot be an `A` either.
Maybe use composition instead?

---

Update based on your specific case: There are a couple of ways that you can sort this out.

First off, does a `SceneNode` really need to be non-copyable, and if so, why? If this is a pure design decision, it is now apparent that it was the wrong one, since you're now in need of a copyable `SceneNode`. If the decision is technical (for example, there is bookkeeping data that is hard to clone correctly), you can try solving that problem. Failing that...

Could your `SceneNode` be movable instead? Move semantics are generally simpler than copy semantics to implement, and standard containers are perfectly happy with movable-only values. But even in that case...

Could your `SceneNode` be a simple interface instead? You only mention being able to call a drawing function. This does not sound related to any copying business, so maybe an interface with a pure virtual `draw` function is all you need. Otherwise...

If you really can't budge these requirements (at which point I would be surprised, but let's pretend), you can simply use a container of `std::unique_ptr<TileLayer>`. These don't require anything from their pointee, and can be stored in containers at will.

And then there's a whole 'nother batch of techniques that could fit you case. Don't forget that OOP and inheritance are just one way to crack that nut, but C++ offers many more tools and techniques besides it. But first, make it work :)

Comment: To be honest, that's what I thought, but I just wanted to make sure :)

Comment: I don't think I can use composition, I have a hierarchy structure and the children of the root node need to inherit from its class so that I can pass drawing and update calls recursively through the structure. thx for responding, guess I'll need to come up with some kind of work around to solve this

Comment: I was hoping for a miraculous save with Boost.Preprocessor :(

Comment: @StoryTeller That might be possible if we get hold of the X for that Y ;)